# cron job giving me error on functioning script

Tags: php, cron

I'm pretty new to cron jobs so this might be an easy answer but I can't figure out what is going wrong here. I'm using a cron job to run a php script to rename a file. I know the script works because when I load the php file it does what it is supposed to do. However the cron job sends me an error email every time. Here is the script I'm running:

```
<?php
rename("login/pools.php", "login/poolsbk.php");
?>
```

I am using the cron command: php -q /home/dollarca/public_html/renamescript1.php

and here is the error it generates: Warning: rename(login/pools.php,login/poolsbk.php): No such file or directory in /home/dollarca/public_html/renamescript1.php on line 2

From the error it's putting out, it seems to me that it is trying to rename a file within the script instead of the files in the directory. Am I using the wrong cron command?

Comment: is the `login` directory a sub of your `public_html` directory?

Comment: what's the absolute path to the file you're wanting to rename? Is it possible you're actually wanting to rename `/login/pools.php` instead of `login/pools.php`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The working directory when `cron` runs the job is different than the working directory you are manually running the script from.

The easy solution is to use the full path in the function.

```
rename("/home/dollarca/public_html/login/pools.php", "/home/dollarca/public_html/login/poolsbk.php");
```

Comment: Sounds logical, I'll give this a try now

Comment: Well it doesn't appear to be working but I'm not receiving any errors anymore. My server time might just be way off from my own time though. I'm gonna set the time for an hour from now and try again

Answer (score 2):

I suppose if you run the PHP script manually, you do it from the directory `/home/dollarca/public_html`. If cron runs it, it won't do that. What you should do is to either use absolute file paths (i.e. `/home/dollarca/public_html/login/pools.php` instead of `login/pools.php`) or use the `chdir()` to change to that directory first:

```
<?php
chdir("/home/dollarca/public_html");
rename("login/pools.php", "login/poolsbk.php");
?>
```